# Trigger Azure Function when all processes are done

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to do trigger an Azure Function **only when all items are processed** in the Queue?

I have a Queue containing multiple Validations that needs to be done. Only after all the validations are validated it should trigger the next Azure Function that will create a report out of these validations

What I've tried

- After an item is process store the result (`validations.Processed = True`) and then do a check

  ```
  bool allProcessed = !validations
      .Where(v => v.LabFormulierId == validation.LabFormulierId)
      .Where(!x.Processed)
      .ToList()
      .Any();
  ```
- Add it to a temp Table, and remove it from the table when the items are finished processing

  ```
  bool allProcessed = !validationsToDo
      .Where(v => v.LabFormulierId == validation.LabFormulierId)
      .ToList()
      .Any();
  ```

---

And then later on check if all are processed with this var, and **only then** fire off the next Azure Function

```
...
if (allProcessed)
{
    await createReportQueueCollector.AddAsync(formulier);
    log.Info($"Add Formulier {formulier.Guid} to create-report queue");
}
```

Both did not work for me... Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your code it's not clear what `validations` are and whether you store them externally.

Have a look at [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview), they provide higher level API to correlate multiple actions. Queues are used behind the scenes but in a way hidden from developer.

Comment: Validations are a set of rules based on the Input, doesn't really matter in this question (I think) They are stored in Azure Blob Storage